# Regex to match words containing X, Y AND Z

Tags: regex

I've been thinking of some random things lately, and this one caught my fancy.

How do I write a regexp for a word which contains X, Y and Z (or for that matter any combination of letters), but not necessarily in that order.

I tried

```
[^xyz]*x[^xyz]*y[^xyz]*z
```

But this searches in that order only

We could do

```
[^xyz ]*[xyz][^xyz ]*[xyz][^xyz ]*[xyz]
```

But that is just useless because it also matches only xy.

I am aiming for a regexp that will match *words which contain x, y and z in all of the following orders*

- xyz
- xzy
- yzx
- yxz
- zxy
- zyx

**EDIT**

Forgot to add this before (sorry bout that)

How about also making it match words like

abxcydz (x, y and z come in any order as above)

Comment: Are you sure that regex is the right tool for that task? This can be solved trivially (and in a much more readable way) by other means (`if text.contains(X) and text.contains(Y) and text.contains(Z) do ...`).

Comment: @Heinzi, sure, but what would be the fun in that? :P
The thought just caught my fancy, and my objective was not for it to be readable or trivial, just to see if it is doable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean all three letters? If so, then:

```
(?=\w*X)(?=\w*Y)(?=\w*Z)\w*
```

Answer (score 4):

If the engine supports [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*x)(?=.*y)(?=.*z)
```

or

```
^(?=[^x]*x)(?=[^y]*y)(?=[^z]*z)
```

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky: Given `yxz` then yes.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
xyz|xzy|yxz|yzx|zxy|zyx
```

Of course this will get cumbersome as the number of letters increases, so you can either do lookaheads (as per Felix's answer) or substring checks (as per Heinzi's comment).

Answer (score 0):

I would think a simple character class would do the trick.  If you just want to see whether a subject contains x, y and/or z then just use the following:

[xyz]+

Comment: This will match the strings "xy" and "yxbz" which contain none of the six strings listed in the OP's question.